# Translator on a string in python issue

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, translation

I am creating a string out of a css string that I modified. 
After the modification the results is this:

```
.cls-24 {\n    fill: lime;\n    opacity: 0.5\n    }\n.cls-25 {\n    fill: none;\n    stroke: #333;\n    stroke-miterlimit: 10;\n    stroke-width: 35px\n    }\n.cls-26 {\n    fill: #333\n    }\n.cls-27 {\n    fill: #7f6145\n    }\n.cls-28 {\n    opacity: 0.2\n    }'
```

I of course do not need those white spaces and the '\'.
The closest I got was doing this:

```
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', ' \\n\t\r')
    changed_css_as_string =str(sheet.cssText).translate(translator)
```

And the output is as follows:

```
.cls-24{fill:lime;opacity:0.5}.cls-25{fill:oe;stroke:#333;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:35px}.cls-26{fill:#333}.cls-27{fill:#7f6145}.cls-28{opacity:0.2}'
```

Which is closer but the main issue is that there are no 'n' anymore. the none is now oe. That's no good. What can I do in order to get the desired output?

Comment: Hi! :) More code please! The generation of the string mentioned at the beginning would be interesting. Do you know the function `.replace('old', 'new')`? Like `'old'.replace('old', 'new').replace('new', 'blah')` or `str.replace('\n', '')` to remove newline. If this is not enough, you can also use RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash `\` before `\n`!

## Wrong

```
translator = str.maketrans('', '', ' \\n\t\r')
```

Remove five chars: , `\`, `n`, `\t` and `\r`

## Fixed

```
translator = str.maketrans('', '', ' \n\t\r')
```

Remove four chars: , `\n`, `\t` and `\r`

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Just posted what worked eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it out, this did the trick:

```
translator = str.maketrans('', '', ' \t\r')
css_without_newline_chars = str(sheet.cssText).replace('\\n', '')
changed_css_as_string = css_without_newline_chars.translate(translator)
```

Comment: Ah, OK, it looks like you had the `\n` stored as two symbols, namely as backslash and `n`.